# instantiating multiple WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, instance

Suppose you are controlling a set of industrial devices through WCF services. Each device will host their own WCF service. Let's call this generic WCF service `MyDeviceController` I want to write once and deploy on each device. However for testing purposes, I also want to deploy all the WCF instances on one local box.

Given this context, how do you deploy multiple instances of a WCF services both local and multiple boxes?

If I am being too vague, please help me clarify my question. I more than happy to edit it.

Comment: You can have as many service hosts (1 instance of service per host) as you have resources for on the same box.  Each service host will need its own unique endpoint. So, for example, you could have `http://server/device1`, `http://server/device2`, etc - each would run in its own `ServiceHost`.  Alternatively, since its the same service, you could put it in one `ServiceHost` and expose multiple endpoints, but I think that might be a little different than what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an easy to handle service host once:

```
public static class SimpleServiceHost<ServiceContract, Service>
{
    private static Thread hostThread;
    private static object _lockStart = new object();
    private static object _lockStop = new object();

    public static bool IsRunning { get; set; }

    public static void WaitUntilIsStarted()
    {
        while (!IsRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

    }

    public static void Start(Binding binding, string host, string path, int port)
    {
        var serviceUri = new UriBuilder(binding.Scheme, host, port, path).Uri;
        Start(binding, serviceUri);
    }

    public static void Start(Binding binding, Uri serviceUri)
    {
        lock (_lockStart)
        {
            if (hostThread == null || !hostThread.IsAlive)
            {
                hostThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                {
                    using (ServiceHost internalHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service)))
                    {
                        internalHost.Faulted += new EventHandler((o, ea) =>
                            {
                                IsRunning = false;
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("The host is in the faulted state!");
                            });
                        internalHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceContract), binding, serviceUri);

                        try
                        {
                            internalHost.Open();
                            IsRunning = true;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            IsRunning = false;
                        }

                        while (true)
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                });
            }

            hostThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        lock (_lockStart)
        {
            lock (_lockStop)
            {
                hostThread.Abort();
                IsRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So if you are willing to use multiple contracts you can just call like this:

```
SimpleServiceHost<IService, Service>.Start(new BasicHttpBinding(), "localhost", "TestService", 8086);
```

Otherwise make my service host work like a factory and return instances when calling start. You probably will need to enhance the class to fulfill your requirements. But you save a lot of code especially when you need to dynamically host several services ;-)

Regards
Jan